# ArcMap trace the creation/modification/deletion events by windows user for all changes (not only the latest change)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, editing, trace

I want to check whether there is a way to trace all the creation, modification and deletion events in the editing session. What I aware now is how to get the latest updated information of an object in the attribute table of a layer.

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: Do you have SDE? are you interested in an ArcObjects soloution?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I have a SDE, I am also interested in ArcObjects.

Comment: You can respond to the IEditEvents OnCreateFeature, OnChangeFeature and OnDeleteFeatue events to get this information as it happens and then copy the feature out to a temporary workspace to catch each "version" of the feature as it's modified/removed. Simplest case is to use replica (check-out) and then export to a delta table to show what features were added and removed (modify is removed and then added)

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the idea. I am using enterprise geodatabase, the check-out replica target geodatabase should be enterprise geodatabase right? I tried to use XML file but failed.

Comment: No, the check-out target is a file/personal geodatabase that is edited as normal and doesn't require connection to SDE until the check-in. Enterprise to enterprise replication can be a two-way replica or one-way replica but is not usually a check-out.

Comment: Are you after each edit that was made to each feature or do you just want to identify which changes have been made prior to reconciling to the database?

Comment: Hi Michael, if possible, I just want to identify which changes have been made prior to reconciling to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify changes before they are committed to the SDE database it is best to use a check-out replica (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000v5000000). A replica database references a version in the SDE database (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Replicas_and_geodatabases/003n000000vp000000/), if you have multiple check-outs each one must have its own version; to remove a check-out simply [delete the version](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000p7000000) from SDE and it is no longer referenced **this can not be undone, a check-out that no longer has a version cannot be reconciled**.

A replica (check-out) is a personal or file geodatabase that has a copy of the SDE data referenced by that version and internally has delta tables, which cannot be seen in Catalog. To view the delta tables you can export them using [Export to Delta](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000011000000) which will provide a feature class of the added features and a table of the OIDs of the deleted features. A feature that is modified is present in the delete table and the add feature class.

Note: export to delta does not destroy the version, you can still use the data and export delta tables again as many times as you need prior to synchronizing changes.

When you want to apply the changes to SDE use [Synchronize Changes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Synchronize_Changes/00170000001s000000/) to post the replica.

To simplify the workflow I find it easier to use the distributed geodatabase tools - they used to be on a toolbar but now are not:

[image]

Create a toolbar and drag these tools onto it using the customize dialog; there are wizards here that make the whole process much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. The distributed geodatabase still on my toolbar. :)